# Разработка android программ на web языках

Tags: javascript, android, css, html5, веб-программирование

Вопрос пожалуй даже слишком тривиален, но в интернете ясного ответа я не нашел.

Так вот собственно и вопрос: **Можно ли писать программы под андроид платформу на веб языках, таких как HTML5, JS, CSS(может быть) ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android понимает только Java. Что бы писать на других языках под Андроид Вам понадобится компилятор, который в конечном счете превратит Ваш код в Java-код.

Есть [React Native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/), который позволяет компилировать почти чистый React-код в Android/iOS приложения, но он настолько сырой, что я бы не советовал начинать с ним работать если нет другого выхода.

Comment: ахах, очень вовремя принял ваш ответ

Comment: лучше поздно, чем никогда